# Empty href attribute on anchor element works in HTML but not in Twig

Tags: symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3, twig

I am using bootstrap to do some collapsing and toggling of tabs and content. I will link the entire code at the bottom of this. Now, for right now the page I am working on is a static twig page. I was having trouble getting some linking to work in twig so I pulled the code to a plain html page just to see what happens. Basically, I have a `<a href="">Hide</a>` which basically collapses/hides the active tabbed content. Now, the problem is, in twig(with symfony 2) if I do that it goes to the home route. If I do href="/pagename" it just reloads the same page and I dont want it to do that. How do I get what it is working in plain html to work in my twig file?

p.s.: It's best to copy paste the code in your code editor because jsfiddle and codepen did not work properly for this code for some reason.

p.s.2: What I am trying to accomplish is on page load to have 4 links, and upon clicking one of them for new content/div element to appear. If I click on one of the other 3 links the div that is visible changes accordingly (bootstrap's dynamic tabs). Each of the 4 divs/tabs have a Hide link which upon clicking needs to close the collapsed tab/div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3 text-center"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#one">One</a></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 text-center"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#two">Two</a></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 text-center"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#three">Three</a></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 text-center"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#four">Four</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="one" class="tab-pane">
              <h3>Content One</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
              <p class="text-right"><a href="">Hide</a></p>
            </div>
            <div id="two" class="tab-pane">
              <h3>Content Two</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
              <p class="text-right"><a href="">Hide</a></p>
            </div>
            <div id="three" class="tab-pane">
              <h3>Content Three</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
              <p class="text-right"><a href="">Hide</a></p>
            </div>
            <div id="four" class="tab-pane">
              <h3>Content Four</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
              <p class="text-right"><a href="">Hide</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, I am aware that I can just use toggleClass to remove the active class which is what shows/hides the tabbed content but I am trying to use that as last resort.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `href=""` to `href="#"` and see if that works out for you. ;-)

Comment: Please attach some explanation to your answer.

Comment: Johnny - that doesn't close the tabs because it tries to go to an element with an id which doesn't exist.